# Latest Orca screen reader on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: accessibility, orca

I would liKe to install the latest version of Orca screen reader on Ubuntu 22.04 due to some issues related to the Ubuntu repo one.

What are the alternatives without go through the pain of a source compile?

I searched on:

- snapcraft
- flathub
- gnome apps nightly
- AppImageHub

Comment: Are these "issues" reported bugs? If so, a link to the bug would be helpful. If not, what sort of "issues"?

Comment: Gnome applications are tested and compatible within a release. They don't promise other-version compatibility, so it's possible that Orca 45 (latest) is incompatible with a  Gnome 42 system (Ubuntu 22.04).

Comment: @user535733 but other Gnome apps are available at the latest release through FlatHub (for example: https://flathub.org/en-GB/apps/org.gnome.Boxes)

Comment: If you install `flatpak`, then sure, more variety is possible. One assumes you already tried that route before asking your question.

Comment: @user535733 thanks for your help. Before asking I've searched on flathub and snapcraft but I didn't find Orca.

Comment: Without using `flatpak`, less variety is possible. Just the release it's built for.

Comment: do you need to stick with 22.04? why not install 23.04?

Comment: With my work station I move only from LTS to LTS